# How to Pass long value to ksoap request

Tags: blackberry

I am facing an issue while passing long value to ksoap request.As ksoap accepts only string and object parameters but i need to pass a long value to the request. Can anybody help me out in this issue.

Request.addProperty("Room No",userid);

Userid is of long type.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Long` instance instead of `long` primitive:

```
Request.addProperty("Room No", new Long(userid));
```